# Calc vector mapping: shape of result

Tags: calc

What determines the shape of the result of a vector mapping (`V M`)?  I had thought it was directly based on the shape of the input, but have a look at this.

`k f` factors an integer, returning a vector of its prime factors.  Given a vector of *n* integers,

```
[27 31 33]
```

`V M k f` will factor all of them, yielding

```
[[3, 3, 3], [31], [3, 11]]
```

which is what I'd expect.  But if all of them are primes, for example

```
[31, 37, 41]
```

then the output of `V M k f` is

```
[ [ 31 ]
  [ 37 ]
  [ 41 ] ]
```

The shape (`H v l`) of the first result is `[3]`; the shape of the second result is `[3, 1]`.  Why?

Comment: Both cases return a vector of vectors. In the second case, as all vectors are length 1, it is equivalent to a matrix, thus `[3,1]`. Similarly, factoring a vector of 3 squares `[9,25,49]` yields a matrix of size `[3,2]` because all results are vectors of size 2.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I was thrown by the difference in how the result is displayed, plus the inability to do certain further mappings in the second case.